# How to replace window.plugin (which is deprecated) in push plugins PhoneGap/Cordova 4.0?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pushwoosh

I try to implement Push-notifications to my Cordova (Phonegap) app (**version 4.1**).

As you know **window.plugins is removed after Cordova 4.0**.
https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/DeprecationPolicy

But most Plugins like [PushWoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin) or [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) still use **window.plugins** in their code which now have become unusefull.

1. Could you advice some work **plugins for pushes** in Cordova 4.0+?
2. If possible – could you advice how to change [PushWoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin) plugin for new Cordova?

Answer (score 2):

Cordova has replaced the window.plugins with the function cordova.require()
             You need to look for the namespace in which the plugin is defined.
             For pushwoosh it's: "com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification"

So instead of:

```
var PushNotification = window.plugins.PushNotification;
```

try this:

```
var PushNotification = cordova.require("com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh.PushNotification");
```

Comment: That's correct. The plugin itself is fully compatible with the latest Cordova. I'm going to push the update of the guides and sample projects tomorrow for Cordova on Pushwoosh.

Comment: How do you find the namespace of plugins?  For instance do all window.plugins.??? need to now use this cordova.require approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that Pushwoosh plugin has been updated to support Cordova 4.0

The plugin version is 3.5.0

Thanks!